# Rotating Square Function JS Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I am looking for a function that draws a square with a function on the canvas, i.e. drawSquare();, with a parameter "degrees" that tilts the square. I **do not** want to tilt the canvas. Thank you, and if you have questions, please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without tilting the canvas

```
function drawRotatedSquare (x, y, width, height, rotate) { // rotate in radians
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y); // overwrite existing transform
    ctx.rotate(rotate);
    ctx.fillRect(-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
}
```

You can do the deg to radian conversion, I have never understood why everyone wants to do that.